# KeyCloak SSO with mutiple application and 2 Server

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have setup 2 key cloak server and each has one web application and want to implement SSO between 2 application

1. Application 1 setup in Key cloak server 1 and Application 2 setup in key cloak server 2
2. login to application 1 and its ask for login page.
3. Enter the credentials and login
4. There is link to application2 in appication and click on it
5. I want to  implemenet Single Sign On (SSO) for application2 ,it should not asked for credentails and login to application with out login page

Any finding appreaciate it

I have tried with IDP ,it still asking login for 2 appication

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.